# In Ext.js changing the value of checkboxgroup

Tags: javascript, checkbox, extjs

I have the following I wrote:

```
{
    xtype: "checkboxgroup",
    fieldLabel: "Content type",
    name: "content_type",
    id: "fx-form-content_type",
    rows: 1,
    value: 0,
    editable: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    queryMode: "local",
    horizontal: true,
    hidden: false,
    listeners: {
        change: function(cmp, value) {

            //console.error(cmp.down("checkbox[inputValue=1]"));
            //console.error(cmp.down("checkbox[inputValue=0]"));

            //var vod_or_npvr = value["content_type_vod_or_npvr"];
            console.error(cmp);
            console.error(value);
            /*
            if(vod_or_npvr === 0)
            {
                Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(2);
            }

            else if(vod_or_npvr === 1)
            {
                Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(1);
            }
            else if(vod_or_npvr === [1,0])
            {
                Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(0);
            }
            else {
                Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(3);
            }*/

        }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: "checkboxfield",
        fieldLabel: "VOD",
        checked: false,
        //name      : "content_type_vod_or_npvr",
        inputValue: 1,
        id: "fx-form-content_type-VOD",
        value: 1,
        labelWidth: 40
    }, {
        xtype: "checkboxfield",
        fieldLabel: "NPVR",
        checked: false,
        //name      : "content_type_vod_or_npvr",
        inputValue: 0,
        id: "fx-form-content_type-NPVR",
        value: 2,
        labelWidth: 40
    }]
}
```

How can I change the value of the `checboxgroup`?

I need it to get wither both `checboxes`, none or one of them. I'm trying to do it with the change listener and `setValue` functions but it doesn't work.
Can anyone understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`CheckboxGroup.setValue(false)`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup.html#method-setValue) for resetting all items of that or if you want to resetting particular items then just use [`CheckboxGroup.down(your item here)`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup.html#method-down) and then again use `.setValue(false)`.

You can check here with working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2ot3).

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'form',
            title: 'Checkbox Group',
            width: '100%',

            bodyPadding: 10,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            bbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Reset All',
                handler: function () {
                    var checkboxgroup = this.up('form').down('checkboxgroup');
                    checkboxgroup.setValue(false)
                }
            },{
                text: 'Reset Item 2',
                handler: function () {
                    var checkboxgroup = this.up('form').down('checkboxgroup');
                    checkboxgroup.down('[inputValue=2]').setValue(false)
                }
            }],

            items: [{
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Two Columns',
                // Arrange checkboxes into two columns, distributed vertically
                columns: 2,
                vertical: true,
                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'Item 1',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '1'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 2',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '2',
                    checked: true
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 3',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '3'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 4',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '4'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 5',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '5'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 6',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '6'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do cmp.setValue(val) in my application it throws an error, or doesn't change anything. So what can I do to deal with it?

Comment: try to debug the code check there is method available or not

Comment: I got this error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'VOD' in 2
It's got a setValue() method but for some reason it's doing something weird
Any idea why it happens?